# Test doesn't show up

Tags: testing

I have created a test orb.test for my module and placed it within the module directory. Installed the Simple Test module. When I visit the /admin/config/development/testing my test orb.test its not listed. Here is the code for my test

```
class OrbTestCase extends DrupalWebTestCase {
  protected $privileged_user;


public static function getInfo() {
  return array(
    'name' => 'Orb Test Case',
    'description' => 'Ensure that Online Booking functions properly',
    'group' => 'Examples',
  );
}

public function setUp() {
    parent::setUp('orb');
    $this->privileged_user = $this->drupalCreateUser(array('allow online  reservations'));
    $this->drupalLogin($this->privileged_user);
}

public function testorbroomavailability() {
  $this->drupalGet('orb');
  $this->assertText('Room Status');
}
}
```

Have I missed something here?

EDIT 5th August 2014:
My tests written and placed in of my modules do not show up in the list of tests (admin/config/development/testing)

Comment: Yes U have. I use the devel module to install and reinstall the module.

Comment: How is your test file named? Where is it exactly placed?

Comment: "Have I missed something here?" Well there is a lot of stuff you do *not* tell us.  Without knowing *exactly* what you've done, it is impossible to tell what you've missed.

Comment: @tunic mymodule.test placed in the module folder.

Comment: I think Free Radical's answer is absolutekly right, some of the points he talks must be failing in your setup.

Comment: Can you edit in your full directory listing for that module (ls -R) and your .info?  And can you double confirm that you are uploading to the proper place and have cleared caches?

Comment: Under what *group* on `/admin/config/development/testing` are you looking for the Orb Test case (for reference, see screendump in my answer below)?

Answer (score 1):

Your test class look OK.

There is no need to install or enable the **Simple test** module if you're using Drupal 7.  Instead, you should enable the core **Testing** module.  (Don't know if installing **Simple test** will make a difference, but it were *not* present when I went through the routine described below.)

Provided it exists inside your module's directory, you're using Drupal 7, have enabled the core **Testing** module, cleared the cache, and made sure to declare your test file with the correct name in your module's `.info`-file, nothing should stop it from appearing in the list included in the "Examples" group when you visit `/admin/config/development/testing`.

Here is how it looks on my site (after I've gone through the steps outlined above):

[image: screen dump]

Comment: Nope. Done all that you have mentioned. Doesn't show the test group :-(

Comment: There is no "test" group.  You're placing it in the "Examples" group. Have you looked there?

Comment: my issue seems stranger the fiction! I have removed the examples module from my laptop, cleared caches but it still appears in the list of tests. So it seems like a cache issue. For some reason it doesn't seem to be updating the list. I am using drupal 7.22 At one point I had a doubt if I was copying the module to the correct VHOST directory, which I definitely was. Very strange behaviour.

Comment: My module.info file was missing this line "testing_api = 2.x" and hence was not not showing up.